# Pandas: Group by contiguous time blocks

Tags: python, pandas

I have API access logs with a timestamp user ID and request payload. I want to group by user and contiguous requests within 1 minute of each other and aggregate a count within each block. So if I had:

```
@timestamp               @data      @id                                                                                                               
2023-01-21 09:46:33.478   ...      Gh8Z4
2023-01-21 09:46:33.690   ...      Gh8Z4
2023-01-21 09:46:34.189   ...      Gh8Z4
2023-01-21 09:48:28.282   ...      Gh8Z4
2023-01-21 09:51:27.652   ...      HVtpG
2023-01-21 09:51:28.682   ...      Gh8Z4
2023-01-21 09:52:17.412   ...      HVtpG
```

I would like to see something like:

```
@id           start                    end             count                                                                                                                  
Gh8Z4 2023-01-21 09:46:33.478  2023-01-21 09:46:34.189   3
Gh8Z4 2023-01-21 09:48:28.282  2023-01-21 09:48:28.282   1  
HVtpG 2023-01-21 09:51:27.652  2023-01-21 09:52:17.412   2
Gh8Z4 2023-01-21 09:51:28.682  2023-01-21 09:51:28.682   1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [`groupby.agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.aggregate.html) with a custom grouper (generated with [`diff`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.diff.html) and [`cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html)):

```
df['@timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['@timestamp'])

group = df.groupby('@id')['@timestamp'].apply(lambda s: s.diff().gt('1min').cumsum())

(df.groupby(['@id', group], as_index=False, sort=False)
   .agg(**{'start': ('@timestamp', 'min'),
           'end': ('@timestamp', 'max'),
           'count': ('@timestamp', 'count'),
          })
)
```

Output:

```
     @id                   start                     end  count
0  Gh8Z4 2023-01-21 09:46:33.478 2023-01-21 09:46:34.189      3
1  Gh8Z4 2023-01-21 09:48:28.282 2023-01-21 09:48:28.282      1
2  HVtpG 2023-01-21 09:51:27.652 2023-01-21 09:52:17.412      2
3  Gh8Z4 2023-01-21 09:51:28.682 2023-01-21 09:51:28.682      1
```

Comment: Also, why the change to the second line where you added the `apply` method instead of calling `diff` directly?

Comment: Sorry for bombarding the comments, but that apply update now prints out a warning: `FutureWarning: Not prepending group keys to the result index of transform-like apply. In the future, the group keys will be included in the index, regardless of whether the applied function returns a like-indexed object`. I'm assuming we don't want to group keys here?

Comment: @Verbal_Kint 1- because the first version would mix the groups in the `cumsum`. 2- this is not an issue, just a warning for the future. You can add `group_keys=False` to disable it, but this is not an error, just a message to inform users of an upcoming change to pandas API.